# hibernate event detecter

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a DB running on Oracle. I use Hibernate for data access. I want to be notified whenever an object is saved in the DB, so that I can do some custom work. I want an "event listener" if you could call it that.  Is there a way to detect such task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Hibernate level, this is done using [interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html)

On Oracle level, it's called trigger:

```
create or replace trigger <triggername>
before/after insert or update or delete
on <tablename> 
for each row/for each statement
...
```

Comment: is it possible instead to use interceptors in Hibernate to intercept a persistent object before it is saved, updated or deleted ?

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake . is it possible instead to use interceptors in Hibernate to intercept a persistent object <b>AFTER</b> it is saved, updated or deleted ?

Comment: Have you looked into the Interceptor example? See the afterTransactionCompletion() method, which is called AFTER the object is saved/updated/deleted.

Comment: hi mhaller, thanks for telling me about Hibernate interceptors but I can't make it work even though I followed the reference step by step : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701793/hibernate-interceptors-aftertransactioncompletion