# hibernate interceptors : afterTransactionCompletion

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I wrote a Hibernate interceptor :

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

private boolean isCanal=false;

public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable arg1, Object[] arg2, String[] arg3, Type[] arg4) throws CallbackException {

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        System.out.println("Inside MyInterceptor(onSave) : "+entity.toString());
    }
    if(entity instanceof Canal){
        isCanal=true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx){
    if(tx.wasCommitted()&&(isCanal)){
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            System.out.println("Inside MyInterceptor(afterTransactionCompletion) : Canal was saved to DB.");
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the method onSave executing fine, but afterTransactionCompletion method never gets executed even though the transaction is successfully commited to the database.

I need a way to track every time a Canal object is successfully saved to the DB and react by printing some messages. is that feasible ? and how ?

Here is the method I use to save objects in the DB :

```
public static Object enregObjet(Object obj) throws UpdateException,
        EnregException, ErreurException {

Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        Session s = InterfaceBD.currentSession();
        tx = s.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // Positionner les champs dteUti et dteUtiModif
            Method dteUtiSetter = null;
            ;
            // Objet en insertion
            dteUtiSetter = obj.getClass().getMethod("setDteUti",
                    new Class[] { java.util.Date.class });
            dteUtiSetter.invoke(obj, new Object[] { new java.util.Date() });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            ;// Le champ dteUtiModif n'existe pas
        }
        // Enregistrer
        IardNum.numeroterCode(obj);
        IardNum.numeroterId(obj);
        s.save(obj);
        s.flush();
        tx.commit();
        try {
            String id = "";
            // Positionner les champs dteUti et dteUtiModif
            Method idGetter = null;
            // Objet en insertion
            idGetter = obj.getClass().getMethod("getId");
            id = (String) idGetter.invoke(obj);
            Connection conn = InterfaceBD.getConn();
            IardGenerator3.cleanSeq(id, conn);
            conn.close();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            ;// Le champ dteUtiModif n'existe pas
        }
        catch(ClassCastException ex){
            ;//just ignore it because we are dealing with a PK class (e.g : CausesAnnexesSinistrePK).
        }
        s.clear();
        return obj;
}
```

Comment: Is a TransactionManager configured? In which container are you running this?

Comment: I edited my question. I posted the method used to insert objects in the DB. I insert objects from a session bean.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using DAO design template. Basicaly you just create an class, which will save Canal object and use it everywhere where you need to save it.
In this class you can add all logic you need.